# Storing a number from HTML form to MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, format, separator

From an HTML form, I get the value of an input with

```
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['price']);
```

I then query MySql with

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE products SET product_name='$product_name', price='$price' WHERE id='$pid'");
```

In the form, the number is displayed with a comma (e.g. `18,000`). But when I update the database I only got `18` stored.
It seems that MySql is taking the comma as a decimal point and then remove the 000. The field in the database is INT(16).

I expect to store it as 18000 then I can display in PHP with `number_format($price)`

Answer (score 0):

Since your database column is INT type which does not support values with comma.

You can replace commma using

```
$price = str_replace(",", "", $price);
```

And for display in PHP, you can use `number_format($price);`